# How to get previous version File object to get web parts?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, csom

I want to create a code which fetches all the version of the publishing page along with the web part.

Here is the code which I have developed to get the version numbers of the page.

```
foreach (ListItem pageItem in pagesColl)
{
    string pageVersion = "";
     List<string> pageVersions = new List<string>();
    //Dictionary<string, string> pageVersions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    /* pageItem.File.Versions will not get the latest version of the file.
     * i.e. if file's current version is 3.0 then pageItem.File.Versions will
     * include only 1.0 & 2.0
     */

    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersion itemVersion in pageItem.File.Versions)
    {
        pageVersion = itemVersion.VersionLabel;
        pageVersions.Add(itemVersion.VersionLabel);
        //pageVersions.Add(pageVersion, itemVersion.Url);

    }
    if (pageItem[CommonConstants.UIVersionString] != null)
    {
        // Adding latest version of the file in the pageVersions collection.
        pageVersions.Add(Convert.ToString(pageItem[CommonConstants.UIVersionString]));
        //pageVersions.Add(Convert.ToString(pageItem[CommonConstants.UIVersionString]), Convert.ToString(pageItem[CommonConstants.EncodedAbsUrl]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pageVersions.Count; i++)
    {
        // getting the web parts of the page of particular version
        GetWebparts(ref pageProp, Convert.ToString(pageItem[CommonConstants.EncodedAbsUrl]), web, pageVersions[i], (i == (pageVersions.Count - 1)));
    }
}
private void GetWebparts(ref MigPage pageObj, string pageUrl, Web web,string versionNo, bool isLastVersion)
{
    // Getting the page from web
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageUrl))
    {
        bool undoCheckOut = false;
        if (isLastVersion == false)
        {
            int intVersion = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(versionNo) *512;
            pageUrl = pageUrl + "?PageVersion=" + Convert.ToString(intVersion);
        }
        File pageFile = web.GetFileByUrl(pageUrl);                
        web.Context.Load(pageFile);
        web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

When I am getting the page file using the URL i.e. `PageVersion=` it is throwing an exception: `One of the identified items was in an invalid format`

What should I do to get the web parts of the previous version pages?